# Matplotlib Donut Labels/Annotation position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to recreate this exact style of this donut chart, but I can't figure out how to adjust the labels/annotations to be in this same position and underlined.

[image]

I found an annotation program example online, but I don't understand it enough to make the necessary adjustments.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

labels= 'x', 'y'

data = [1266.97, 746.79 ]  

wedges, texts = ax.pie(data, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5), startangle=225)

kw = dict(arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
           zorder=0, va="center")

for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1)/2. + p.theta1
    y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
    x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
    horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
    kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
    ax.annotate(data[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.35*np.sign(x), 1.4*y),
                horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment,  **kw)

ax.set_title("title")

plt.show()
```

The above code creates the following donut, but I can't figure out how to adjust my label lines to match the above example.

[image]

Comment: what are the other requirements besides underlined?  Do the values have to be in the same position?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the values in the same position as the example, also with the underline. The position is more important to me than the underline if I had to pick.

Answer (score 2):

You are determining the position of the labels with these lines:

```
y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
```

You can instead set the position of the text manually like so:

```
annotation_postions = [(-.5, .5), (.5, .5)]
for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1) / 2. + p.theta1
    print(i)
    y = annotation_postions[i][1]
    x = annotation_postions[i][0]
    horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
    kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
    ax.annotate(data[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(3*x, 1 * y),
                horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw)
```

`xy` is where the line starts on the chart.

`xytext` is where the text is located

The underline is just the line extending below the text.  You'll have to research how to make it longer and put the text ontop of it.

Comment: You'd probably want to set the anchor point of the left label to its bottom left corner and the right label to the bottom right corner.

Comment: I adjusted the code a bit to move the labels up on the donut. I also flipped which one was negative. With your answer the labels where showing up on the wrong sides. Still researching placing the text on line.                                                                                  annotation_postions = [(.4, .9), (-.4, .9)]